# Using knitr generated video with pandoc & slidy

Tags: slideshow, knitr, rstudio, pandoc

I am writing a slide-show in Rmd (markdown) using Rstudio & Knitr (Ubuntu 12-04). I generated some videos with the chunk option `fig.show='animate'` that can be seen well with the knitr generated HTML.

Then I use pandoc to generate the slidy HTML code but then the videos are not displayed and the following message is shown:

> Could not find the video format and MIME type supported

Does anyone know how to make these videos work with slidy?

Comment: What does `grep mp4 /etc/mime.types` tell you? I have met this problem before (not me, but one of RStudio developers), but I do not know why it happens.

Comment: @Yihui  grep mp4 /etc/mime.types  
   audio/mp4a-latm  
   video/mp4     mp4  
   video/mp4v-es

Comment: Seems to be a problem with firefox and mime.types but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: If you are sure it is a Firefox problem, you can tell how Firefox should handle MP4 files in the preferences (`Edit->Preferences->Applications`).

Comment: I tried with that but no change at all.